# Any delegate method for contentOffset change notification after deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, uitableview

After deleting some bottom rows with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, my table view shrinks in length and it is scrolled down automatically to compensate the loss of these bottom rows which means its contentOffset is changed.

The problem is that `scrollViewDidScroll:` is not called in this case. Is there any other delegate method I can use to get notified of the contentOffset change here?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for Key-value observing.

Try adding this to your controller:

```
        [tableView addObserver:self 
                    forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"
                       options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                       context:nil];
```

You can then implement this method in the controller.

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject: (id) object
                        change: (NSDictionary *) change 
                       context: (void *) context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]) {

        //Do Something with content offset

    }
```

}

However, this notification will probably fire every time you scroll since you are observing the contentOffset property.  I recommend observing the **contentSize** property instead, which should only fire this notification when rows are added or deleted.

Comment: KVO of `contentOffset` is overkill. Besides, KVO(whether of `contentOffset` or `contentSize`) has a noticeable delay.